# Replacing in place only on specific column using bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a table delimited file that looks like this:

[image]

I want to replace all instances of the `*` character with `""` (empty space) and all instances of `/` with `" "` (space) ONLY in one of the columns.

The output would look like this:

[image]

What is the best way to do this?
I am doing this on very large files and I would prefer to replace it in place.

Initially I used this:

```
sed -i 's/\// /g' test_file.txt  #this will replace / with ' ' (space)  
sed -i -e 's/\*//g' test_file.txt  # this will replace * with ''
```

But this replaced the indicated patterns in all columns across the file. I need to operate only on one in particular

Comment: Your question is not clear, please do add clear samples in CODE TAGS + try to mention more realistic samples(try avoiding putting dots in samples please) by using button `{}` and let us know then.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Replace the images in your question with concise, testable, **textual** sample input/output. Something we could copy/paste to test a potential solution against. See the previous comments for how to format your text and code.

Comment: wrt `I am doing this on very large files and I would prefer to replace it in place` - all tools that claim to have an "inplace editing" option (sed, perl, gawk, ruby, etc.) create a temp file internally. `ed` doesn't create a temp file but uses a buffer the size of your input file in memory so that's not a good solution for operating on large files. So if when you say "I would prefer to replace it in place" you're thinking that'll save from a temp file or memory being used - no, it won't. You **WILL** either use a huge buffer with ed or a temp file internally or externally with any other tool.

Comment: Whilst not the answer you are probably looking for, I have found that the Sublime Text 3 editor is very good at this sort of thing and will work quickly with very large files. It has full regular expression capability and "knows" dozens of file format types. It has a column mode and, of course, it has the Ctl-Z undo capability so you can tweak your find-and-replace until it does exactly what you want without having to keep a backup copy and "save" will replace the original like all editors.

How big are the files?

Comment: @Stef_92 You now say "Hey, we are talking about multiple files with trillions of records. Several TBs of data. I will need to implement this in bash as part of a much larger script executed on a server." This would have been useful information in oyour OP.

Comment: Cool. See the earlier comments (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58148410/replacing-in-place-only-on-specific-column-using-bash?noredirect=1#comment102681351_58148410) for how to get help. Also tell us what awk version you're using (try `awk --version`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with awk. Make sure you the correct column seperator (Here I assume ,).

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{gsub(/\*/, "", $2); gsub(/\//, " ", $2)} 1' input > output
```

`gsub` replaces globally in the indicated column. The `1` is just a shorter way of writing `{print}`.

Comment: Superb! thank you. I made a small addition to 'mimic an in place replacement' but it worked well.                                                                                                             
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '{gsub("*", "", $2); gsub("/", " ", $2)} 1' meta.csv > temp && mv temp meta.csv

Comment: @Stef_92 that's fine but it might not be necessary.